Add custom namespace in custom command
I'm trying to create a service class with a custom command.
Currently if I run php artisan make:service TestService it will be generated with the namespace App\Services in the Services folder, but if I run php artisan make:service Test/TestService it will be generated in the folder Services/Test, but the namespace will still be App\Service, when it should actually be App\Services\Test
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\GeneratorCommand;

class MakeService extends GeneratorCommand
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'make:service {name}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Create a Service class';

    public function getStub()
    {
        return app_path() . '/Console/Commands/Stubs/make-service.stub';
    }

    public function getDefaultNamespace($rootNamespace)
    {
        return $rootNamespace . '\Services';
    }

    public function replaceClass($stub, $name)
    {
        $class = str_replace($this->getNamespace($name) . '\\', '' $name);

        return str_replace('{{ service_name }}', $class, $stub);
    }
}

my stub
<?php

namespace App\Services;

class {{ service_name }}
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        
    }
}


If you add quotes around Test/TestService, does it work?

@aynber Yes, the class name continues to generate normally

I know almost nothing about Laravel, but can you update your stub to include namespace {{ namespace }};? I'm basing this off of https://laravel-news.com/customizing-stubs-in-laravel#content-custom-controller-stubs

"... when it should actually be App\Services\Test" You have namespace App\Services; hardcoded in your stub, why do you expect it to be App\Services\Test?

Looking at ConsoleMakeCommand.php, you may need to call $stub = parent::replaceClass($stub, $name); in your replaceClass before you do anything else. I'm not quite sure you need to override replaceClass, though

what you need to do is divide the user's input by the character / and take all the pieces except the last one
Example

public function replaceClass($stub, $name)
{
    $name_parts = explode('/',$name);
    $class_name = $name_parts[count($name_parts)-1]; // get last element
    $namespace = implode("\\", array_slice($name_parts, 0, -1)); // implode all without last element
    $namespace = $namespace !== "" ? "\\". $namespace  : ""; // if extra namespace exist prepend with \

    $stub = str_replace('{{ service_name }}', $class_name, $stub); // inject class name
    $stub = str_replace('{{ service_namespace }}', $namespace, $stub); // inject namespace
    return $stub
}


and obviously the stub becomes
<?php

namespace App\Services{{ service_namespace }};

class {{ service_name }}
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        
    }
}

